# Почему на странице в случайных местах отображаются юникодные знаки вопроса?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, utf-8, razor

Сайт на Asp.Net MVC с использованием Razor. Периодически в случайных местах встречаются вот такие знаки вопроса, при этом остальной русский текст отображается нормально.

[image: Юникодный знак вопроса на странице]

Положение и этих знаков зависит от контента страницы: если контент перед знаком изменится хоть на байт, знак либо исчезнет, либо переместится. Если контент до этого знака не изменяется, то он стабильно показывается при каждом обновлении страницы. Очевидно, что он появляется при какой-то деформации двухбайтовых символов. В кодировках везде выставлен UTF-8.

Есть предположение, что по каким-то причинам байты портятся на стыке двух TCP-пакетов. Я знаю, что TCP-протокол транспортного уровня, обеспечивающий целостность и непрерывность данных на верхнем уровне, но другого объяснения я не нашел. Как и не нашел причины, почему TCP может портить стыки пакетов.

Проблема проявляется на разных серверах с одним и тем же сайтом (перевозил пару раз), и даже на разных сайтах, созданных независимо друг от друга с нуля из стандартных шаблонов.

**UPD**

Пример поломанной строки: Не обработ�н.

Байты этой же строки:

0xD0, 0x9D, 0xD0, 0xB5, 0x20, 0xD0, 0xBE, 0xD0, 0xB1, 0xD1, 0x80, 0xD0, 0xB0, 0xD0, 0xB1, 0xD0, 0xBE, 0xD1, 0x82, 0xB0, 0xD0, 0xBD, 0x0A

Здесь видно, что в первом случае буква "а" кодируется 0xD0, 0xB0, а во втором (поломанном) случае 0xB0, 0xD0. Байты по каким-то причинам поменялись местами.

Comment: Сохраните результат HTTP запроса как есть и посмотрите, что там за последовательность байтов возникает.

Comment: Покамест это «подземный стук». Покажите релевантный код. Может быть, вы неправильно сохраняете текст (например, превращаете байты каждого пакета в строки и конкатенируете, а не наоборот).

Comment: @Athari , обновил вопрос, привёл пример поломанной строки.

Comment: у вас же есть данные для воспроизведения и код. вы пытались отладить локально с теми же данными? строка тоже ломается?

Comment: @PashaPash, данные очень сложно подобрать, поэтому локально не отлаживал. Но на продакшене периодически появляется такой символ.

Comment: @Almeonamy вы же пишете что на продакшене стабильно воспроизводится до смены контента. стяните себе базу и воспроизведите.

Comment: @Almeonamy Вы случаем не из браузера сохраняли или копировали? Просто в этой строке уже плейсхолдер, а не реально сгенерированный символ.

Comment: @PashaPash, я не смог повторить такого эффекта с той же базой данных. Возможно, локально этот баг не повторяется, но я не могу быть уверен, что абсолютно все байты  были одинаковые.

Comment: @Athari, я сохранил html-файл из браузера, открыл notepad и скопировал строку. Наверное, обманул сам себя. Что можно использовать, чтобы получить эту строку исходной?

Comment: @Almeonamy запишите запрос фиддлером

Comment: @Almeonamy `WebRequest.Create()`. :) Прямо в отладчике можно будет посмотреть байты.

Comment: @PashaPash, дополнил вопрос последовательностью байт из фиддлера.

Comment: @Almeonamy что-то самописное в пайплайне есть? сжатие, например? Что-нибудь еще, что работает с респонсом как с набором байт?

Comment: @PashaPash, cамописного ничего нет. Сейчас вспомнил, что на сервере используется сжатие gzip.

Comment: Поищите по коду `Response.Filter = `. Если найдете - я подскажу фикс

Comment: @PashaPash, в проекте такого нет.

Comment: @Almeonamy это может быть что-то стандартное. отключите сжатие статики и динамики. проверьте значение `Response.Filter` в отладке.

Answer (score 2):

Такое может быть вызвано некорректной реализацией `HttpResponse.Filter` (самописного, или готового стороннего).

Код подключения фильра обычно выглядит как

```
Response.Filter = new MyFilter(Response.Filter);
```

Проверить наличие фильтра можно под отладчиком - посмотреть тип текущего значения `Response.Filter`.

ASP.NET пишет респонс в фильтр кусками через метод:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    ...
}
```

и если фильтр не знает про юникод - то он обрабатывает куски "как есть", разрезая их на средине символа.

UPD: проблема так же можнет быть вызвана [одним из уже исправленных багов в New Relic Browser Monitoring](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/net-release-notes):

.NET Agent 2.25.208.0:

> Fixes a problem where Unicode characters were not being correctly written to the page in some cases when Browser Monitoring was enabled in the agent.

.NET Agent 4.1.134.0:

> Fixed a bug that caused the .NET agent to corrupt some non-HTML resources if browser monitoring was enabled.

Стоит обновить агента до последней версии.

Comment: В `Response.Filter` вроде бы лежит System.Web.HttpResponseStreamFilterSink. Если я не ошибаюсь, это стандартный обработчик. Проверял на продакшене. Ещё вспомнил, что на сервере используется NewRelic для мониторинга. Теоретически он мог бы изменять выходной поток, но я не знаю, как это проверить.

Comment: @Almeonamy relic точно правит контент (только не уверен как именно). отключите end user monitoring в релике. проверьте что скрипт со страницы исчез. если поможет - пишите им в саппорт (и тут заодно, а то у меня тоже релик в приложении)

Comment: @Almeonamy нашел. обновляйтесь.

Comment: У меня версия 3.1, т.е. новее той, в которой исправлен этот баг. Однако я отключил мониторинг в браузере, после чего этот баг найти нигде на сайте не смог. В ближайшие дни постараюсь обновить агент и попробую включить мониторинг в браузере. Если баг больше не всплывёт, отмечу ответ.

Comment: @Almeonamy лучше попробуйте обновить до последней версии и включить мониторинг. Если баг сразу вылезет - пишите в саппорт реплику.

Comment: Обновился, включил мониторинг, пока полёт нормальный. Надеюсь, этих багов больше не появится.

Comment: Снова нашел баг уже после обновления NewRelic до последней версии.

Comment: @Almeonamy пишите им в саппорт, если баг точно пропадает после отключения диагностики

Answer (score 1):

Такая ситуация возникает, когда две проблемы с кодировкой частично компенсируют друг друга.

Допустим, файл у вас написан в кодировке `utf-8`. Но при этом Razor читает его как `windows-1251`. В итоге получается белиберда, однако эта белиберда оказывается "в целом корректна", за исключением тех символов, которые не причитались. Потом белиберда отдается в кодировке же `windows-1251` браузеру, в котором срабатывает автоматическое определение кодировки по сигнатуре, и те же самые байты показываются вам уже в кодировке `utf-8`. Итог - Вы видите исходный текст, за исключением символов, потерянных при преобразованиях.

Проверьте кодировку на всех этапах: в каком виде она хранится в файле (правильная кодировка должна находиться в секции `system.web/globalization` вашего `web.config`).
Проверяйте поведение всяческих промежуточных прокси-серверов, если таковые есть. Ну и конечно же проверьте, совпадает ли отданная серверов в заголовках кодировка с той, которую определил браузер.

Comment: Все файлы проекта в utf-8. В заголовке ответа utf-8. В web.config тоже utf-8. Идея мне понравилась, но вроде везде нужная кодировка.

Comment: А эти самые строки, в которых появляются знаки вопроса - вообще из файла читаются или из БД? Как они в БД при этом хранятся?

Comment: В разных источниках. Иногда это строки из БД, иногда в самом cshtml-файле. От источника не зависит.

Comment: Очень даже зависит. У вас на каком-то этапе сменяется кодировка. Про TCP - это шаманизм, в 3 ч ночи после 100-ой кружки кофе. Может из js скрипта енкодится, а потом на сервере декодируется некорректно.

Comment: @hardsky, я не очень понял, о чём именно вы говорите. Про шаманизм - это да. Но js я не использую в данном случае, а сломанные строки попадаются в разных контекстах в разных местах. Кодировку на ходу вроде нигде не меняю. Если есть идеи, на каком этапе это может происходить, я готов проверить.

Comment: У меня была проблема с кодировкой, когда данные для post запроса кодировались на клиенте с помощью js метода, на сервере соответственно одним из методов .Net-а. Подробностей не помню.

Comment: @Almeonamy, комментарий был к тому, что данный ответ кажется правильным. Нужно проверить кодировку по всей цепочке, кодировка htm страницы (директивы view-хи может быть), используются ли различные методы encode/decode, кодировку в базе.